# Showing a form via Form.Show is not given focus?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I two forms, Form1, and a UserControl which hosts Form2. Within that UserControl on Form1 I call `Form2.Show();`. I have also tried `Form2.Show(this);`. Either way, the focus is not given to the form. I have to click once within the new form to give it focus, and then I can click items within that form.

I figured that control is passing back to my main control/form, and thus the focus is getting lost. So I am waiting until Form2 is closed via:

```
      while (form2.Visible == true)
      {
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
          Application.DoEvents();
      }
```

This seems to work. However after I close the form, now the reverse holds true. Form1 is not given focus (even if I call `this.Focus()`) until I click once within the main form window.

Any ideas how to handle this properly. I want to show a child form (modeless) and immediatley be able to click on it, and when that form is closed, immediately be able to take action back on the parent form.

Comment: A user control that *hosts* a form?  Is it just creating it and calling Show() or does it actually act as a parent for the form with the form's TopLevel property set to false?  Show the user control code.

Comment: It just acts as a parent. It is a ComboBox where I am 'dropping down' my own ListView rather than the standard dialog. This ListView is hosted in a form (I couldn't find a way to just display the ListView directly.). I will look into adding the UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This came from the fact that I was overriding WndProc in order to display the form. When I received the CBN_DROPDOWN message, I would display the form. I fixed this by instead Invoke'ing the method that shows the form and it fixed it.

```
case CBN_DROPDOWN:
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(Show_DropDown));
    return;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `.ShowDialog()`, this can also be extended to give your response on if the user performed Form2's operation properly or aborted early.

This does make the form locked in focus up front and will halt your code execution on the first form till that form is closed.

Comment: The problem is that I want the user to be able to act on the main form as well, and when they do so, it will close that form. Sort of like a Popup.

Answer (score 1):

use `this.Activate();` in place of `this.Focus();`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow completely, but from your UC try opening Form2 like this:

```
form2.Show(Parent);
```

This should specify the UC's Parent form as `form2`'s owner.